# Date object is not working inside angular js interpolation inside htmll

Tags: angularjs, string-interpolation

I want to create a date object inside an html using interpolation

```
{{ new Date(newMatchedData.requestInfo.loadTimeStamp) | date:"MMMM" }}
```

but this isn't working, it is showing an error message saying that a new line or semi colon is needed

What to do now?

Comment: what is your time stamp? angular date filter accepts values like `1522321741294`. Otherwise you should cast `new Date(...)` inside your controller

Comment: My time stamp will be like '2018-03-01 05:00:00', now will be able to use new Date inside the html interpolation or should I use it in controller?

Comment: it can't parse this _string_, it would need to be in ISO 8601 format, or numerical number (milliseconds since 1970 UTC), or Date format. So just cast it in the controller: `$scope.newMatchedData.requestInfo.loadTimeStamp = new Date($scope.newMatchedData.requestInfo.loadTimeStamp);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to create a new Date object to apply the date filter if your date is correct. Just do the following and you will se the month of your date

```
{{newMatchedData.requestInfo.loadTimeStamp | date: 'MMMM'}}
```